# Get _csrf in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

How can I get _csrf object (?!) in spring controller? I've configured Spring Security and can get ${_csrf} request attribute in jsp files. 
I've tried:

```
CsrfToken _csrf = (CsrfToken) session.getAttribute("CsrfToken");
CsrfToken _csrf = (CsrfToken) session.getAttribute("_csrf");
```

the result is null;

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In debug I saw a session attribute with a key "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN". I viewed the [HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.html) class. It has a method for loading token from incoming HttpServletRequest object.

Finally this worked for me:

```
CsrfToken token = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository().loadToken(request);
```

I will be grateful if someone explains me how this works.

Comment: You are basically extracting the token from the server request header that is coming from the AJAX. If you want to get the `headerName`, `getParameterName`, and `token`, you can get it using `CsrfToken token = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository().loadToken(request).getHeaderName();`, `CsrfToken token = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository().loadToken(request).getParameterName();`, and `CsrfToken token = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository().loadToken(request).getToken();` respectively.

Answer (score 7):

To access the CSRF token in a Spring controller you can simply do this:

```
@Controller
public class FooController {
    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public void foo(CsrfToken token) {
        // Do whatever with token
    }
}
```

Spring will automatically detect that you want the token, based on the type of the parameter, and inject it into your method.

This works since at least Spring Security 5.0 and if you are using Spring Boot or have the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation in your configuration.

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-csrf-resolver)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) session.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @NikolaB. But it gives null. In debug I see a session attribute with a key "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN".

Comment: What is the 'session' variable?  How do you get a reference to it?

Comment: You should be able to inject it in controllers (Spring will manage this): @Autowired private HttpSession session;

Answer (score 1):

I think in your earlier attempts, you were mixing up the CSRF parameter name with the session attribute name, and also trying `CsrfToken.class.getName()` which may or may not have been used in earlier versions. So simply, you had the right idea but the wrong key.
If you look at the source code for `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository`, you'll see it defines the following defaults:

```
private String parameterName = DEFAULT_CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME;
private String headerName = DEFAULT_CSRF_HEADER_NAME;
private String sessionAttributeName = DEFAULT_CSRF_TOKEN_ATTR_NAME;
```

The first one is the parameter name for when the token comes as a POST parameter, the second is the header name for when it comes in the request header, and the third is the key for storing it in the session. The method `loadToken` doesn't actually get the token from the request object - it gets the session object from the request and then looks up the token, which it earlier stored with the key defined by `sessionAttributeName`.

Answer (score 1):

This also works if you want to get it directly from the `session`

```
CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) session.getAttribute("org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have `HttpServletRequest` instance inside Controller's resource method as a parameter. Using this request object you can get the csrf token easily.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/test")
public class TestController {
   
  @GetMapping
  public String test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    CsrfToken csrfToken = 
           (CsrfToken)httpServletRequest.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    if(csrfToken != null)
      return csrfToken.getToken();
    return "Token Not Found";
  }

}
```

Csrf Token value used to create using `java.util.UUID` class, as following:-

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Check `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository` and `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository` classes which are implementation of `CsrfTokenRepository`, inside `spring-security-web-X.X.X.RELEASE.jar`.

If you want to have the CSRF token in cookies with response at client side (say browser) then:-

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http
     .csrf()
     .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
     .and()
     .....
     .forLogin();
   }
}
```

1. Enable the csrf and use `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` csrf token repository.
2. Fetch the token from cookie with cookie name - "XSRF-TOKEN"
3. Use this token in another requests [except GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS] header with header key as `X-XSRF-TOKEN`